# How do I execute dynamic code in a container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl, docker-exec

I'm working on a personal project involving a browser-based code editor (think https://repl.it). My plan:

1) Constantly stream the code being written to a remote docker volume on kubernetes.

2) Execute this code when the user presses "run".

I've already started working on the streaming infrastructure, and have a good grasp on how I'd like to do it. Regarding the code execution, however, I'm in need of some guidance.

Idea A: I was thinking that I could have two docker containers, one web server and one "environment", sitting on the same VM. When a request would come into the webserver, it would then run a `docker exec ...` on the environment.

Idea B: I use `kubectl`, specifically `kubectl exec` to execute the code on the container.

A few things to note. I want to make the "environment" container interchangeable, that is, my app should be able to support python, js, etc.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. THIS IS A VERY BAD IDEA DO NOT DO IT
2. You would want to run each snippet in a new container for maximum isolation.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying what "IS A VERY BAD IDEA"? I've changed the naming of my bullets above slightly (from Idea 1/2 to Idea A/B).

Are you suggesting that I spin up a new container every time the user executes their updated code? I'm worried that the overhead of creating/destroying containers is too much considering that any given user will be using the same environment for all of their development.

Comment: Making containers is very cheap, that's kind of what they are for :) As for what it is a bad idea, containers are not bulletproof. The isolation is at best imperfect and it's a serious full-time job to stay on top of all the emerging security issues. Running untrusted code from the internet can be done, look at hosted CI tools, but it's not something to be taken lightly or you will immediately be awash in bitcoin miners and spam bots.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the reply! For this use case, let us make the assumption that our users are all 'non-adversarial'. Also, our containers could be pretty heavyweight; so spinning them up/down every time a "run" is issued could take some time.

With that being said, if we have a persistent environment container, and we do a `kubectl exec` on it (with the syncing code that the user is writing), is this a reasonable approach? Considering the above assumptions, would you do this any differently?

Comment: No, that approach is not reasonable. Even a "heavyweight" container takes milliseconds to launch. The only slow bits are the image download and those are heavily cached.

Comment: Got it. With the assumption that we spin up a new docker container for each snippet, how do you suppose we do this in the realm of kubernetes?

If we have a web server running as a Kubernetes deployment (i.e in a container/pod) that is accepting requests for new code to be "run", how do you suggest that we create containers for this code on the fly? Should we be creating pods on the fly? From what I've read, this is slow (on the order of seconds). Any thoughts?